# Coefficients of the polynomial approximation of $|x|$

Tags: polynomials, approximation, approximation-theory

I am looking for a polynomial $p_n$ of degree at most $n$ that will approximate $|x|$ in the interval $[-1,1]$ with $\||x|-p_n\|_\infty=O(\frac{1}{n})$ and will have coefficients whose absolute value is monotonically decreasing with $n$ as fast as possible. Something of the sort $|a_i|=O(1/i!)$, where $a_0,\cdots,a_n$ are the coefficients of $p_n$. Is there some known result of this spirit?

Comment: With $\|.\|_\infty$ you meant sup on the real line? If so then it is not possible as $p_n$ must be $x+a$ for $\sup_{x\in \Bbb{R}}||x|-|p_n(x)||$ to be bounded.

Comment: @reuns Thank you for this comment, I meant over the interval $[-1,1]$. I've edited my question above.

Comment: The convolution  $f_n=|x|\ast n e^{- \pi n^2 x^2}$ approximates $|x|$ and it will be analytic whence equal to its Taylor series, picking the first few terms will give what you want.

Comment: @reuns, Thanks. Do you mean to take any arbitrary $n$ or does $n$ affect the error of the approximation $\|f_n-|x|\|_\infty$?